# Insert a string. Create new string which is the mirror reverse of the inserted one around its center

Tags: javascript, arrays

The formula must work in these words.

```
Input               Output

“stranger”          “ngerstra”
“rotator”           “torarot”
```

Comment: I'm confused... Those words have been manipulated differently. Do you want the center letter(s) to stay where it's at?

Comment: my word is STRANGER, it must change like ngerSTRA
half of my word must change his place to front

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? What is the question here?

Comment: @ErikHarutyunyan then the second example should have bben "atorrot" or "torrota". And why not "gerstran" in the first example? What are your rules?

Comment: So shouldn't ROTATOR be torROTA? Not toraROT

Comment: The are no question, i should change place of that word, half of my word to go to begining

Comment: I guess for odd letter counts it leaves the center letter alone and just swaps the substrings before and after it.  Either way, the OP forgot the part where he describes a programming problem and asks a question...

Comment: to write formula , which change those 2 words

Comment: @ErikHarutyunyan: *"The are no question"* - So when you came to a *Question & Answer* website and clicked on *Ask A Question*, did it occur to you that you might be asking a question?  You are encouraged to learn more about this community and how we may be able to help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You're right, there are no question

Comment: OK, how to solve that problem

Comment: @ErikHarutyunyan: Grab a pencil and paper, walk through some examples of input and output, and attempt to define a consistent set of logical steps which would produce the desired output.  Choose a programming language (JavaScript is a reasonable choice you appear to have made) and encode that logic into code.  (If you are not familiar with the language at all, start with some introductory tutorials on it.)  Test and debug your attempts as needed.  If you encounter a problem with that code, such as an error or unexpected behavior, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: @David thank you so much, for helping, i'll try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The Basic Idea

So with this solution, it's quite simple, you have your dictionary, then you make a slight change to each object within the dictionary, you basically add some string to it so that if a word is `'card'`, it'll swap the order of the letters in such a way that when you search for `'drac'`, card will appear to be a similar word.

### A bit more detail

When you search for words similar to what you've got in your dictionary, to prevent outputting exactly what you've already searched, when constructing a new array, it'll push `null` onto the array if index `x` is the same word as the word searched.

Then, once the array has been constructed, it filters out all values set to `null`.

```js
// Simple string sort function. 
const sort = s => [...s].filter(x => x != null).sort().join('');


// Helper function which will state whether or not to push 
// a string onto the array or push null onto the array. 
const push = o => w => sort(o) === sort(w) && o != w ? o : null;


// A function that takes an array of words and a word
// via the use of currying, then magic happens! 
const anagrams = d => w => d.map(o => push(o)(w)).filter(s => s != null);
  
 

// The proof is in the pudding... 
const dictionary = ['stranger','ngerstra','torarot','rotator'];
const word = 'ngerstra';
const otherWord = 'rotator';
const results = anagrams(dictionary)(word);
const otherResults = anagrams(dictionary)(otherWord);
console.log(results);
console.log(otherResults);
```

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote? It simply solves the problem and I've provided a reasonable level of detail with regards to a description.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess because your answer solves a problem that isn't somewhere close to what the OP talked about.

Comment: @Jeff I mean the question was so unclear that it could be specifically and only what you said, or something more flexible, like my solution, who knows?